# How to call generic controller by even though we pass different controller name in the URL

Tags: .net, model-view-controller

There is some functionality were we need to call an API controller even though we give different name in the URL for example

localhost:123/api/User and Localhost:123/api/Account should call one generic controller i.e. for example GenericController all the time.

The above functionality is requied as UserController and AccountController are having same funtionality as that of GeneriController.

Please provide me some clue to poceed and implement this kind of functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using ASP.NET MVC? if so take a look at routing.

This is a good source, but there are a lot youtube video's available that will explain routing

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx